# Talend - command line to execute a Job

Tags: talend

I'm looking for a possibility to execute straight from a linka JOB in my Talend ESB repository backend.
I was thinking something like

```
C:\Talend\EBS\Studio\TOS_ESB-win32-x86.exe --job=jobXXX
```

I cannot use Karaf or deploy a local BATCH file, I must use the ESB backend.

THank you
regs

Comment: If you have the Enterprise Edition then you have a complete REST API that can be used to do that, see https://help.talend.com/reader/YcEtLnE30CM8SeOxtXyHYQ/p4dbJNuFkgFs0_~GMUWdmA

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using community edition: is there a possible workaround?